# The "Single Activity Architecture" - Multiple device layouts...what am I missing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, design-patterns, android-jetpack

I am currently writing and app and recently come across the "Single Activity Architecture" which seems great on first glance, 
using `fragments`/`SupportFragmentManager` to load fragments in to a 'container' programatically.

Now in practice, I am having an issue with the pattern, namely with having separate device layouts.

[image: Example]

Assuming we are using one Activity.kt class, how can we use the FragmentManager to achieve the above? Using the one Activity class for all devices/orientations, the code seems far too coupled to the layouts to achieve the pattern. You'd need code such as:

```
if layout == tablet AND Landscape -> do this fragment transaction
if layout == phone AND portrait -> do this fragment transaction
if layout == television AND landscape -> do this fragment transaction
```

It seems to quickly become a rather bad and messy "un-scaleable" pattern as opposed to having fragments just placed in the various XML layout files for the devices...

Or is the pattern really only intended for say a simple app layout scenarios (say phone only)?

Any enlightenment would be great.

Ref Link:[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8i73ic/its_official_google_officially_recommends_single/)

Ref Link:[Android Dev Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui

Comment: I would only use this pattern with simple apps. Also sometimes you don't need multiple layouts, as one can be rotated automatically when the user changes the device's orientation. Also, some apps lock the orientation to either portrait or landscape, so they don't have that issue either.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz - I asked for a general opinion on design pattern. Linking to Docs that have nothing to do with pattern choice it not helpful.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Thank you. I was hoping this wasn't the case.